# How did this physics stack exchange post solve their Gaussian integral for a moving point charge?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

My question arises from this post: [Gauss's Law with Moving Charges](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/63547/gausss-law-with-moving-charges)

I have tried everything I can think of to solve the integral, and I have absolutely no clue as to how it was solved. I typed it into Wolfram Alpha and attempted to get a step-by-step solution but the computation time exceeded and it wasn't able to show me a step-by-step. I think my issue comes from the denominator being raised to $3\over  2$. How was this integral solved?

\begin{align}
\oint \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{a} &= \oint \frac{k\, q\, \vec{r} \cdot \hat{r}}{r^3}\, \frac{1-v^2}{(1-v^2\, \sin^2\theta)^{3/2}}\, r^2\, \sin \theta\, d\theta\, d\phi \\
&= k\, q\, \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\pi \frac{1-v^2}{(1-v^2\, \sin^2\theta)^{3/2}}\, \sin \theta\, d\theta\, d\phi\\
&= 2\pi\, k\, q\, \int_0^\pi \frac{1-v^2}{(1-v^2\, \sin^2\theta)^{3/2}}\, \sin \theta\, d\theta \\
&= 4\pi\, k\, q~,
\end{align}

Comment: Try the substitution $z= (v/\sqrt{1-v^2}) \cos \theta$.

Comment: Have you tried $\sin \theta d \theta=-d(\cos \theta)$, $\sin^2 \theta=1-\cos^2\theta$?

Comment: @Vasya How does $sin(\theta)d\theta=d(cos(\theta))$?

Comment: @matryoshka: "minus" was lost while typing :)

Comment: @Vasya Sorry, I'm still not sure how they are equal. Is that an identity?

Comment: @matryoshka: Using the chain rule for derivatives http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/ChainRule.aspx $d(\cos \theta)=(\cos \theta)'d \theta=-\sin \theta d \theta$